# Angularjs 1 directive templateUrl failure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

`https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload?p0=dashboard%2Fhello.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found`

And I try rebuild the error in http://plnkr.co/edit/TUFDwgfw5BHRl3VwtUTr?p=preview

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: You are not loading up angular as a script. Anywhere.

Comment: Adding `<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>` to your HTML head section made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve issues like this, try looking at the browser developer tools to see what url is actually requested and see how it differs from the correct url to get the `hello.html` file.

In almost all cases when seeing the difference it becomes immediately clear what's going on.

Comment: So you mean my `hello.html` firle Url  maybe wrong.
I think my element maybe worng in `https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt?p0=hello&p1=modules%2Fdashboard%2Fhello.html`

Comment: Well, the $compiler seems to be unable to find it (it tries some url but gets a 404). If you check your browser developer tools (network tab) you can generally see what the url is that Angular request (and gets a 404 as result). Compare this url to the actual url for the file and you should see where it differs.

Comment: I cant show my local files.But I am sure chrome can find `hello.html` file.

Comment: Wait, the link you posted in your comment 42 minutes ago is a different error than the one you posted in your original question! The error in your comment above states that the content of your hello.html file has more than one root. That has nothing to do with the original error.

Comment: Luckily,it worked.I try this ues one `restrict:'E'`.Yesterday,I uesd 'restrict:'AEMC' in my work. I have a lot of dom elements in the project maybe they affected `directive`.Anyway thank you O(∩_∩)O

Comment: Glad to have been of some help. Would you mind upvoting the answer for me?

Answer (score 2):

See the route path you are mentioning in the file as well as you need to check other JS errors if any.

Me once had the same issue. But looking at the error you will think there is problem with loading of hello.html but in actual the error was in some other JS code in controller.

Hope this will help.

Thanks.

Comment: I try input my ` hello.html` url in Chrome.And its true Chrome can find `hello.html`file.

Comment: Then check the controller code binded to it if there are any errors.